# How to prepare data for spacy's custom named entity recognition?

Tags: python-3.x, nlp, spacy, named-entity-recognition

I'm trying to prepare a training dataset for custom named entity recognition using spacy. My data has a variable 'Text', which contains some sentences, a variable 'Names', which has names of people from the previous variable (sentences). After going through some examples and spacy's documentation, I realised that one has to pass index of the entity while preparing the dataset. I want to know if there's any way to pass the entity as a string directly while preparing the dataset ?

Reference: "https://medium.com/@manivannan_data/how-to-train-ner-with-custom-training-data-using-spacy-188e0e508c6"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, spaCy will need exact start & end indices for your entity strings, since the string by itself may not always be uniquely identified and resolved in the source text.  Examples:

- `Apple` is usually an ORG, but can be a PERSON.
- `Ann` is a PERSON, but not in `Annotation tools are best for this purpose.`

In python, you can use the re module to grab the indices:

```
>>> import re
>>> [m.span() for m in re.finditer('Amazon', 'The Amazon is a river in South America.  Amazon Inc is a company.')]
[(4, 10), (41, 47)]
```

You will have to go through and verify the indices before creating your spaCy training set.

Comment: So having the names already as Entity column doesn't really help ? I will have to anyway find the indices of that word in the 'Text' column using regex as you mentioned, right ?

Comment: Also, sometimes I have more than one entity. How to deal with that ?

Comment: Yes, you will have to find the indices, which you can do programmatically using re module as described, but then you will have to manually eliminate the false positives from the training set.  Note that in TRAIN_DATA, `entities` is a list, so you can keep adding entity tuples:  `TRAIN_DATA = [('The Amazon is a river in South America.  Amazon Inc is a company.', {entities: [(4,10,'LOC'),(41,47,'ORG')]}), ...]`